# Где найти подобный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, slider

Где можно найти такой слайдер?
Суть в том, что он растягивается на всю ширину экрана, средний слайд всегда по центу, желательна возможность придать стили неактивным слайдам, кроме центрального.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите у сайта на исходный код ) Скорее всего название библиотеки найдешь. Дальше уже понятно)

Comment: совет, конечно, правильный, но сайт сделан на конструкторе ".wix.com", и там разобраться в скриптах я не смог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня как-то возник похожий вопрос, и мне кажется, я знаю как Вам помочь.
Плагин называется [jQuery EasySlider](http://www.hoopisfinancialgroup.com/new/hoopisfinancialgroup/js/easyslider.js.txt).
[image: У меня это выглядит так...]